# INNER JOIN registro entre tres tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas

Tengo tres tablas products, categories(las cuales tienen una llave primaria) y la tabla products_to_categories(conectada con las otras dos tablas por llaves foraneas como se muestra en la imagen). El problema es que no logro hacer una cuarta tabla en donde contenga modelo, cantidad (tabla products) con la descripción(tabla categories) a la que pertenece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento. Además, ¿qué SGBD es? ¿MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server?

Comment: Escribe el código que has usado, de esta manera además de darte la respuesta, sabrás cual ha sido tu error. No te olvides de mencionar que Base de Dato usas

Comment: ¿Cuál es la razón por la que quieres crear una cuarta tabla?, a partir de tu tabla ``products_to_categories``  ya puedes obtener las columnas ``modelo``, ``cantidad`` y ``descripcion``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario crear una cuarta tabla si lo que quieres usar los datos de las tablas `categories`y `products` ya tienes la tabla `products_to_categories` y a partir de esta tabla ya puedes acceder a cualquier columna de tus primeras tablas con el siguiente código.

```
select b.modelo,b.cantidad,c.descripcion
from products_to_categories a
inner join products b on b.productos_id=a.products_id
inner join categories c on c.categories_id=a.categories_id
```

Comment: Si funciono :O, lo que no entiendo es que cada registro se repite varias veces

Comment: En realidad lo que sale es el listado que tengas en la tabla ``products_to_categories``, si pudieras crear una nueva pregunta o editar tu pregunta mostrando los datos que tienes y la salida que te brinda puedo responder mejor a tu pregunta

Comment: Ya vi que con 'DISTINCT', puedo eliminar los registros repetidos. Gracias por la ayuda, ya entendi mejor como funciona el INNER JOIN

Comment: No hay problema, éxitos